# Утилита du из Linux, работа с весом папок

Tags: linux, c

Есть функция:

```
unsigned long int directorysize(DIR *d)
{   
    struct dirent *de;
    struct stat buf;
    int exists;
    int total_size;

    if (d == NULL)
    {
        perror("prsize");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    total_size = 0;
    for (de = readdir(d); de != NULL; de = readdir(d))
    {
        exists = stat(de->d_name, &buf);
        if (exists < 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't stat %s\n", de->d_name);
        else
            total_size += buf.st_size;
    }
    closedir(d);

    return (total_size + (HIDE_VOLUME * 2));
}
```

Но она вычисляет лишь размер той папки, в которой мы находимся, как сделать так, чтобы она проверяла и другие папки (Знаю.. можно использовать рекурсию, но всё никак не могу найти, как проверять другие папки)..

Comment: [man 2 chdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) + рекурсия, когда очередной элемент это каталог? Хотя мне симпатичней просто изменять текущий path новым именем каталога, передавать его в рекурсивном вызове и открывать там

Comment: а ещё лучше `man 3 opendir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если Вам нужен **рекурсивный** обход дерева каталогов, то настоятельно рекомендую воспользоваться функцией *nftw*:

> Функция  nftw()  обходит  дерево каталогов, начиная с указанного в
>   dirpath, и для каждого элемента дерева  однократно  вызывает  fn(). 
>   По  умолчанию  каталоги  обрабатываются   раньше   файлов   и
>   подкаталогов, которые в них содержатся (предварительный обход).